# C++ MAPI RecipDesc Initilise

Tags: c++, mapi

I coded my self a Programm to Create Mails.

First i get a Vector of String with Addresses. Now when I try to Inizilise the RecipDesc with the Size of the Vector i cant compile , couse its waiting for a constant.

Here some Code snippets:

```
vector<string> to=Createadresse();
static const size_t v=to.size();

    MapiRecipDesc  rdRecipient[v];
```

I get Following  Erros ( sry the Compile is in German but you will get the Error Code)

```
error C2466: Zuordnung eines Arrays der konstanten Größe 0 nicht möglich.
error C2133: 'rdRecipient': Unbekannte Größe
error C2070: 'MapiRecipDesc []': Ungültiger sizeof-Operand
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: For a value set at run-time you'll need to allocate using 'new'.

Comment: ethrbunny you got it :D Fixxed it with a dynamic Array.
{
     int v=to.size();
      MapiRecipDesc  *rdRecipient= new MapiRecipDesc[v+1];}

thanks anayway =)

Answer (score 1):

ethrbunny you got it :D Fixxed it with a dynamic Array.

```
 int v=to.size();
  MapiRecipDesc  *rdRecipient= new MapiRecipDesc[v+1];
```

thanks anayway =)